# how to make jquery effects immediately after webpage opens

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm new to jQuery... working on an animation-type sequence for an "Enter" page for a website... how can I override the .click function in jQuery so that the "slide" effect starts as soon as the webpage is opened?

here's the code for the slider effect:

```
<SCRIPT>
  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#left").click(function () {
      $(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1200);
});

  });
  </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: you do not want it to happen on click

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the click part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want is for the slide to occur when the page is loaded you don't need to put it in the click event. Try this.

```
<SCRIPT>
  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#left").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1200);
});

  });
  </SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do try

```
<SCRIPT>
  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#left").load(function () {
      $(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1200);
});

  });
  </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: it's not working... the effects aren't starting when the page loads and refuse to start when I click them :S